# Android Studio jar task not working as expected

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have written a jar task to create a jar file from an Android library project. In earlier version of studio the jar task was working properly but in recent version I am seeing happening something surprizing and blowing my mind from last couple of hours.

My Task

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/libs/my_jar_name.jar'
}

task buildJarFile(type: Jar) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
    into('build/libs')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'my_jar_name.jar')
}

buildJarFile.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

What it is doing is something surprising for me. Is is creating a jar under the specified folder `build/libs` like **"my_module_name.jar"** not what I have specified. I have extracted that jar by renaming it as .zip and what I found is that the origin jar lies inside that zip folder with the name I have provided(my_jar_name.jar) along with an META-INF directory.

like

**my_module_name.jar/build/libs/META-INF**

**my_module.jar/build/libs/my_jar_name.jar**

I am not getting why this is happening.

Comment: http://selvin.pl/as1.png so `delete 'build/libs/app.jar` will not work ...

Comment: sorry that is my module name , sorry my mistake. I did not get what you want to show with the image.

Comment: jar is creating and deleting successfully, but the jar is inside an another jar with my mobule name, that is what I am not getting.